# Tkinter: Paste Excel Cells into Different Entry Widgets

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, tkinter

I've created a grid of entry widgets using Tkinter (python 2.7.10). I'd like to have so that if I copy and pasted different cells from an excel file, the cells would paste into separate cells in the widget as well. This is a small snippet of the code that actually creates the widgets.

```
root = Tk()

#create an array of height entries                                                                                                           
height = 5
width = 5
for i in range(1,height+1): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        b = Entry(root, text="")
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)   

#initialize column headers
Label(root, text="Plan ID").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="WACOG").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="Margin").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="Start Date").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="State").grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=W)

excelise = Button(root, text="Excelise!", command=writeToExcel).grid(row=height+1, column=4)
xmlise = Button(root, text="XMLise!", command=writeToXML).grid(row=height+1, column=3)

mainloop()
```

Right now, when I paste, all of the different excel entries is pasted into one entry widget cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to explicitly handle the `<<Paste>>` event yourself, parse the data, and then insert it into the individual entry widgets.